# Conditional Formatting with Filtering - How to highlight the cell with the MIN value of a caculation based on the result of two other cells

Tags: excel

Conditional Formatting - How to highlight the cell with the minimum value based on the result of two other cells. I want to highlight the cell in selected cells in a Row that corresponds to the smallest product in the each column. (Note all value in the rows will be equal to or greater than zero)

Example: Imagine Cells A1:E2 are all filled with numbers, with at least one cell equalling to zero. Here Cells A2, C2, or E2 can be highlighted. Cell E2 is highlighted as E1*E2 is the smallest non-zero product out of the products A1*A2, C1*C2, E1*E2

So far I have used the formula

=A$1*A$2=MIN($A$1*$A$2,$C$1*$C$2,$E$1*$E$2)
applied to A2,C2,E2

Excel 2021

Comment: So, what is the problem with your formula? Post sample data here and then show us what you want? Then explain how to gain that?

Comment: The issue is my formula highlighte the zero instead of the lowerest non-zero product.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 0 5 6     So here my formula would highlight cell c3 with the zero 0 instead of cell a2 with value 2. @Harun24HR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can more than 1 of the 3 fields be = 0?  If only 1 or none = 0, then this works. I've formatted it for clarity since there are multiple nested if's.

```
=A1*A2=IF(  $A$1*$A$2=0, 
            MIN($C$1*$C$2,$E$1*$E$2), 
            IF(  $C$1*$C$2=0, 
                 MIN($A$1*$A$2,$E$1*$E$2), 
                 IF(   $E$1*$E$2=0, 
                       MIN($A$1*$A$2,$C$1*$C$2),
                       MIN($A$1*$A$2,$C$1*$C$2,$E$1*$E$2)
                  ) 
            )
        )
```

Comment: Yes more than 1 of the 3 sides can be zero.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you need to do logically is to exclude any 0 values from the MIN calculation.  You can do that by testing each product, and if 0, change it to a number larger than any possible normal value (I used 9999).  This works:

```
=A1*A2=MIN(
    IF($A$1*$A$2=0,9999, $A$1*$A$2),
    IF($C$1*$C$2=0,9999, $C$1*$C$2),
    IF($E$1*$E$2=0,9999, $E$1*$E$2))
```